# Wordpress api is not working, getting 401 error

Tags: wordpress, rest

I was trying to integrate ship rocket with WordPress,

But when I try to access the URL endpoint to integrate it, getting an error just like below.

**`*The requested URL /wc-auth/v1/login/ was not found on this server..*`**

I have updated  Permalink structure to

`https://hapso.in/sample-post/`  and still getting the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, [REST API endpoint URLs for WooCommerce](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication-over-https) often start with `/wp-json/wc/v3/` or something similar. Yours starts with `/wc-auth/`.

And, make sure your web server implements `mod_rewrite`. If other permalinks work correctly, that is already done.